# How can we identify if a file contains header or not using powershell / azure data factory

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake

Is there any option available to identify the header of a text/csv file dynamically using power shell /azure data factory ?   The solution required to search the file and then need to identify if any header row is there in the file. If it exists then it should remove the header and if not no action.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: yes……………………………..

Comment: Is the name of the any of the header columns known ?  I mean do we know if we will have any column with the name X .

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using ADF: https://kromerbigdata.com/2019/09/28/adf-dynamic-skip-lines-find-data-with-variable-headers/